# Citations don’t show up on Google Scholar

Tags: citations, google-scholar

Google Scholar has successfully listed a paper published two weeks ago. However, most of the references are not included in the citation counts of the papers that are referenced. Has that happened to anybody already? What can I do? Will upload the full text on academia.edu eventually help Google to find the citations?

Comment: Give some time for Google robot to do its job.